# How can I make sure I convert to a single encoding regardless of what type I actually have?

Tags: string, perl, encoding, utf-8, encode

If I get a string inside a perl method but I don't know at that point if it is a specific encoding or not and want to convert it to a specific encoding how do I do that?
E.g. something like the following (could also be UTF-8 instead of ISO8859 for example):

```
sub func {
  my $arg = @_;  
  if($arg not ISO8859) {  
     $arg = Encode::encode("ISO-8859", $arg);  
  }  
  #use $arg    
}
```

**Update:**
Is the following correct? (the intention is that regardless of what is the `$arg` that was passed in the method I make it `utf8` and then I encode it to `iso8859` and get a single representation regardless of input)

```
$arg = Encode::decode("utf8", $arg);  
$arg = Encode::encode("iso-8859-1, $args);
```

The [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) seems to say that what I need is covered

Comment: Have you seen [Encode::Guess](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3a%3aGuess) & [Encode::Detect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode-Detect)?

Comment: @devnull:Actually I am confused on why these are available since http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html it seems to say that `$utf8 = decode($name, $bytes);` takes encoding into account

Comment: @devnull:See update in OP

Comment: Who is calling function()? And where do the data originate from?

Comment: @innaM:It could be from anywhere. From code, over the network etc

Answer (score 5):

Is `80` € or Ђ? Is it even text?

You have to decode inputs in order to do anything with them, and you have to know an input's encoding to decode it.

---

> I don't know at that point if it is a specific encoding or not and want to convert it to a specific encoding how do I do that?

Generally speaking, you can't. How do you expect to instruct `decode` how to decode it if you don't know what it is?

At best you can use heuristics. The more you know about the input, the better heuristics you can use.

For example, if you know a string is encoded with either UTF-8 or iso-8859-1, then you could guess nearly perfectly which one it is. In fact, you could even decode a file that's a mix of both!

> Is the following correct? (the intention is that regardless of what is the $arg that was passed in the method I make it utf8 and then I encode it to iso8859 and get a single representation regardless of input)

No. Those two lines must be provided text encoded using UTF-8. You can't decode something without knowing the encoding that was used to encode it.

Comment: So how can I achieve what I need? I.e. some kind of "normalization" process to always get the same representation regardless of what the input originally was?

Comment: By always decoding on input using the appropriate encoding for that input.

Comment: But this is what I do in the **Update** section, isn't it? `encode` in utf8. So the 2 lines of code in **Update** are correct?

Comment: First of all, the encoding is called "UTF-8" (with dash, case doesn't matter), not "utf8". And no. Those two lines must be provided text encoded using UTF-8. You can't decode something without knowing the encoding that was used to encode it. It'll work if your input is UTF-8. It won't work for anything else.

Comment: So it is not possible to do such "normalization" in generic manner?

Comment: But here ([$obj =] find_encoding(ENCODING)):http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html it says that `decode` finds the encoding first and then decodes

Comment: No, it says it finds "encoding object" (encoding module).

Comment: I see. So there is no way for a "normalization" process?

Comment: Sure there is. The process is to decode your inputs. This normalizes to Unicode code points. As I keep saying this normalisation is a very good thing to do. You don't want to deal with encodings in your code, just when communicating.

Comment: If you meant "is there a way to guess an encoding?" I already answered that as well. e.g. What's the encoding of "\x80"? Is it even text???

Comment: `Sure there is. The process is to decode your inputs` I don't understand this. Shouldn't I already know the encoding to decode it?

Comment: Yes, but not afterwards. That's the very definition of normalization.

Comment: Also what happens if I call encode in an already encoded string?

Comment: Each byte of the encoded string will be treated as a code point, so you won't get anything useful.

Comment: So the gist is that 1)I should call `decode` but only if I know the original encoding 2)If I call encode in an already encoded string I mess things up 3) There is no way to know the actual type of the passed-in string. Are these correct?

Comment: 1) No, you should always `decode`. How do you expect to do anything with a string whose encoding you don't know???? 2) Yes. 3) More or less, yes, but see what I actually said in my answer.

Comment: Ok always call `decode` without caring about what the string is? It is very confusing for me

Comment: It's confusing because it makes no sense. You seem to be deliberately ignoring the answer: Who said "without caring about what the string is"? **You have to decode inputs in order to do anything with them, and you have to know the input's encoding to decode it.**